# Searchable, offline Erlang documentation?

Tags: erlang

Is there a place I can download an easily searchable copy of the Erlang documentation, so that I can use it while I'm on a long flight, for example?

Comment: on linux, you can simply install the erlang-doc package, all html files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://erldocs.com/

you can find download links next to versions for offline viewing.

Answer (score 4):

If you use linux, feel free to try `erl -man ModuleName`, e.g. `erl -man erlang`

Comment: This is good, though it makes it quite difficult to find things unless you know exactly what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check on Linux or OSX, but on windows you have a copy of the documentation in the doc directory of your installation. If ERL is the place where Erlang is installed, you will find the root of the documentation at ERL/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try generate offline documentation http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html use

```
$ make docs
```

Also, you can go to the official Erlang site https://www.erlang.org/downloads, select Erlang version in section **Available releases**, find in loaded page the link **HTML Documentation File** and download archive. Аfter unpacking archiveб go to **otp_doc_html_X > doc > index.html**